# Laravel - must return a relationship instance exception handling

Tags: laravel, orm, exception

I would like to display employee department based on this relation

here is the JobHistory table schema

```
    Schema::create('JobHistories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('employees_id');
        $table->integer('Jobs_id');
        $table->integer('Departments_id');
        $table->date('start_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

here is the employee model

```
    public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany(JobHistory::class,'employees_id','id');
    }

    public function getDepartment()
    {
       $dep = JobHistory::where('employees_id', $this->id)->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')->first();

       return ($dep) ? $dep->department() : '';

    }
```

here is function on JobHistory Model

```
    public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'Departments_id', 'id');
}
```

And finally I want to display it on view like this:

```
    @foreach($employee as $row)
     <tr>
       <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
       <td>
         {{$row->getDepartment->name or '-'}}
       </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

The question is, how to handle exception if an employee does not have any job history yet? I have try using is_null(), empty() and isset() on blade validation. but nothing works.

Comment: Handling exception in this case seems overkill, you probably just want to check the very existence of the department relation - first load & check department and decide upon that - I see what you were trying to do, but that will not work :)  Also "employee" with no job seems a bit odd, but I can imagine a use case...

Answer (score -1):

You can Use ternary operator
Here is solution to your problem

```
{{isset($row->getDepartment->name) ? $row->getDepartment->name : '-'}}
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: `$row->getDepartment->name` will _always_ fail

Comment: can you explain How it will fail? @Hedam

Comment: I have try this. this only work if the employee already have job history data. but if it is empty, it always fail.

Comment: It will fail, as getDepartment is called as an attribute. Laravel will interpret this as a relation, and since the method does not return a relation, it will fail. It should be always invoked via a relationship.